# Bundle addition event listener

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

Is there an event listener for a bundle addition to the bundle context?

I want to catch a bundle before it is installed and added to the bundle context, and then stop it from being added.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent a bundle from being installed?

Comment: I wanted to stop older versions of being installed.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanna catch a bundle before it's installed, before it's added to the bundle context, and then stop it of being added.

This isn't really something to do in code in one of your bundles, this is something to do as part of securing your management agent. If you want to prevent bundles from being installed then you should be enabling security and only allowing `AdminPermission lifecycle` to bundles that should be allowed to install other bundles. If bundles are only ever installed from "outside" the framework (e.g. your framework launcher) then none of the bundles inside should need this permission.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `BundleActivator` interface, as noted in the docs: [this](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html)

Comment: What I'm looking is a solution that wrote in just one place, and catch all the 
new bundles that are being loaded, and before they are installed I can't stop then of being added to the framework. As far as get, Using BundleActivator  I would have to wrote the solution in every bundle.